# Modern cv - WinEdt and MikTex - after Installation on Windows 7 - do not work

Tags: miktex, winedt

I have installed yesterday MikTex and WinEdt 10.3 version on my computer.
I have opened my file which I want to generate, however it always reports a mistake:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \usepackage
                {comment}
? h
The package inputenc has already been loaded with options:
  [utf8]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [ansinew]
Adding the global options:
  utf8,ansinew
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
?
```

The tex file worked on my old computer where I had Microsoft 10 (two days ago), however on new computer not. Is it maybe because of Microsoft 7?

Here is the beginning of my tex file:

```
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[left]{casual}

\moderncvcolor{grey}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% character encoding

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{textcomp}               
 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

% adjust the page margins

\usepackage[scale=0.84]{geometry}

\recomputelengths

\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.0cm}    
                
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
```

.........................

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this issue.

Thank you in advance

Katarina

Comment: As the error says, you can try to remove the line with `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}`  --- That should have errored out anyway... (Your preamble is strange... are you sure is not the result of pasting two different ones together?)

Comment: If your file is utf8 encoded you can remove *both* lines with inputenc as utf8 is the default now, if your file is ansinew encoded, remove the line with [utf8].

Comment: @UlrikeFischer did Windows 7 use utf8 by default? Now that you mention it, maybe not...

Comment: @Rmano there is quite large probability that the file is ansinew encoded. (But naturally it would be a good idea to convert it to utf8, winedt has a menu entry for this).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.